# How to set up a server to attend jmeter calls?

Tags: jmeter

Before going to the question itself, let me do a short introduction to our current situation:
We have 15 customers, for each one of them we run back-end test cases using jmeter, for each customer we have a VM with the nightly build running and a jmeter installation, an external shell script (triggered by Jenkins) calls jmeter in non-gui mode and performs the tests.

Now, what we want to do is to remove all jmeter clients from each of the 15 customers' VMs and install it only in one jmeter-VM to attend calls from this shell script. In other words, each customer VM will contact this server and request the installed jmeter instance to run the test cases.

This lead us to the question:
How to set up a server to attend jmeter calls?
Is this possible?
This server must be able to answer at least 2 parallel requests from other VMs.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not recommended for performance tests, because two JMeters on the same machine will affect each other's results.

However, you're already on VM and results may be affected by virtualization issues. Also you may want just to run functional tests, so:

If you used to run your jmeter tests as remote tests on JMeter-server, then just make two separate jmeter installations in separate dirs and configure different installations to listen  on different ports. Use those ports to choose on which installation to run the test. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html for details

Comment: The solution is valid since I asked to at least run 2 tests in parallel, however, is not the solution I was hoping, I believe that there is no specific way to achieve this with only one Jmeter installation. 
Doing several installations and building something like a load balancer to distribute the test requests among Jmeter installations is good but if I have to, let's say, add a new library, I will have to update each of the installations (that for sure will be less work than having one for each customer) but still not optimal. Thanks for your response.